# Excel Pivot calclated field

Tags: excel, pivot, calculated-field

I am trying to this:

[image]

But it doesn't work - what do i do wrong?

i want to give every region a Target.

Is it even possible to do it via Calculated Field?

Hope someone could help me.

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible, you need to use the if statement and as per your formula your if statement is wrong!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok thank you but then i do not understand what is wrong with IF formula?